# Hacked WordPress blog

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

My WordPress Blog is under constant attack with this URL

```
/page/2/?pretty;board=Themes%253btopic%3Ddefault.0
```

I tried to defend with

```
# BEGIN
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)board=Themes(.*)
RewriteRule . http://www.go.away [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END
```

At my surprise it didnot work so I tried

```
# BEGIN
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page/./
RewriteRule . http://www.go.away [R,L]
</IfModule>
# END
```

This helps but when Googlebot asked for `example.com/page/2/` there will be a problem.
What to do?

Comment: If it's not damaging your server, just ignore it.  Problem solved :)

Comment: What do you mean when you say your blog is under attack?  Is this a DoS type of attack or are they able to alter content somehow?

Comment: Would not a redirect make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your mean about attack is: You are getting too much spam responses to your posts then you can have some kind of captcha implemented in response to allow comments on the post. Secondly there are lots of spam controlling plugins available you can try for them.

And if you are getting attacks on admin panel logins then you can use htaccess to restrict your admin panel access.

Hope it might help you!